# problem with editing a row in datatable using primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have problem with editing datatable with primefaces.
I have tested datatableRowSelection example but it did'nt work.
when I click on the button edit the dialog is displayed but with empty values.
Please Help!
 here is my code:
 in: ListingPage.xhtml, I have:

```
                <p:column headerText="Edition">  
          <p:commandButton update="edition" oncomplete="marqueDialog.show()" image="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil">
              <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{item}"  
                target="#{marqueController.selected}" />  
          </p:commandButton>

</p:column>
```

width="400" height="500" showEffect="explode" hideEffect="explode" modal="true" >

```
    <h:panelGrid id="edition" columns="2" cellpadding="4">
```

```
    </h:panelGrid>  
</p:dialog>
```

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to this question posted shortly before yours...

[Cannot update a componet from p:commandLink 'update' attribute,the Link is persent in p:dataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443626/cannot-update-a-componet-from-pcommandlink-update-attribute-the-link-is-persen)

The inside of the dialog should be in a seperate form from the dataTable.

**EDIT:** To clear confusion, DO NOT DO THIS:

```
<h:form ...>
  ...
  <h:form ...>
    ...
  </h:form>
  ...
</h:form>
```

Also, place a form INSIDE the dialog, do NOT encapsulate the dialog:

```
<h:form ...>
  ...
  <p:dataTable ...>
  ...
</h:form>

<p:dialog appendToBody="true" ...>
  <h:form ...>
    ...
  </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

Something like the above should allow the commandButton update to occur to elements WITHIN the dialog.

Comment: thank you for your response but it did'nt work again.
<p:datatable> is encapsulated in <h:form id="formDatatable">
and <p:dialog..> is encapsulated in <h:form id="dialogForm"> Please can you explain more what I have to do? I'm confused